# How to write a test when a component calls a property function?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I have my working hooks and I want to write a test for it. My problem is, I can't find good reference about how it works.

I want to test if the api is called when the `onClick` event is clicked.

here is my useUser.ts

```
export const useUser = ({
    id,
    token,
    callApi,
}: UserProp) => {
    const onClick = async (): Promise<string> => {
        const rest = await callApi(id, token)
        return rest;
    }
    
    return {
        onClick
    }
}
```

Here is my unit test

```
let hookRes: ReturnType<typeof useHooks>

beforeEach(() => {})
    const prop = {
        id: 1,
        token: 'token',
        callApi: jest.fn(() => {
          return "test"
        })
    }
 
  hookRes = renderHook(() => useHooks()).result.current
})

describe('onClick test', () => {
  test('onClick', async () => {
    await act(async () => {
      await hookRes.onClick()
    })
    
    // make a test here 
  })
})
```